# Cannot open zip file in Windows Explorer which generated by PHP Zip Archive

Tags: php, windows, zip, php-ziparchive

When I trying to open my zip file which is generated by PHP Zip Archive, there is an alert showing

> "Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder
>   'filename' is invalid." error opening in Windows Explorer.

But I can open the file through 7-zip. In some reason, I have to ensure the zip file can open by Windows Explorer. Is there any problem when I generated the zip file? Please help!

```
function create_a_zip($files = array(),$dest = '',$root_folder,$overwrite = false) {
        if(file_exists($dest) && !$overwrite) {
            return false;
        }
        $valid_files = array();
        if(is_array($files)) {
            foreach($files as $file) {
                if(file_exists($file)) {
                    $valid_files[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }

        if(count($valid_files)) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            if($zip->open($dest,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
                return false;
            }
            foreach($valid_files as $valid_file) {
                if(is_dir($valid_file) === true){
                    foreach(glob($valid_file . '/*') as $file){
                        $zip->addFile($file, $root_folder . $file);
                    }

                }else if (is_file($valid_file) === true){
                    $zip->addFile($valid_file, $root_folder . $valid_file);
                }
            }
            $zip->close();

            return file_exists($dest);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

For me, the solution was to use `ob_end_clean()` before outputting zip file contents (as noted by @Ywis in the comments)...

```
ob_end_clean();
readfile($zipfilename); // outputs zip file's content
```

... even if you don't output any characters before that.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem originates from:

```
$zip->addFile($file,$file);
```

Unless you have your php script in the same directory as the files you want to add to zip, you will need to include the file path. The 2nd parameter in addFile is the name of the file inside the zip, so if your $file var includes the path, that’s where the issue probably coming from. Try to change the code to :

```
$filenameonly = preg_replace("/(.*)\/?([^\/]+)/","$2",$file);
$zip->addFile($file,$filenameonly );
```

which will strip out the file path (if any) and leave you only the file name for the 2nd variable in addFile.

If this will solve your problem you will know for sure that the problem was in your filenames and can pinpoint it easily.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I use paths only with alphabets, numbers, dots(.), and underscore(_). So there is no blanks in the path.

Comment: What about non English characters?

Comment: After hours of tracing code, finally I found out that path name is NOT the problem. The zip file generated on the server is **correct** ( can open by Windows' built-in Zip utility), while the download zip file is **incorrect**! Is there something wrong when file transferring? I compared their file size, they are exactly the same......Anyway, still be thankful to your kindly help!

Comment: Then the problem seems to be in your decoding scheme. Can you post your code creating headers?

Comment: I find out that there should be an **ob_end_clean()** before **readfile()**.

Comment: I do not really understand why. But I think the **headers** will influence output buffer? So when **readfile()** executed, it collects some characters that should not be included.

Answer (score 1):

Windows zip does not recognize paths begining with "/"

Just remove the first "/" in the filepath.

Like this:

```
if ( substr($root_folder,0,1) == '/' ) {
    $root_folder = substr($root_folder,1);
}
$zip->addFile($file, $root_folder . $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send as parameter to absolute path for example `$abspath`. Then use it in

```
$filenameonly = str_replace($abspath,"",$file);
$zip->addFile($file, $filenameonly);
```

It works 100% even in Window 8 and even your files you zip are in folders.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using str_replace string function, you can use built-in file-system functions.

```
$zip->addFile(realpath($file), pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
```